# How to do ajax delete on react

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, web

I was wondering if delete works like add but it doesn't. Im using fetch method Im not familiar on react's ajax so I am not clearly sure whats wrong with my code

so here is my code onclick delete

```
deleteEmployee(id) {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
         method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(response) {
     // history.go(0);
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
  });
}
```

this is the code for the table

```
< div className="container">   
          <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
            <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
             <table className= "table table-bordered" id="result"> 
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>
```

code for the calling of the data where the button located

```
renderItem(d, i) {
  return <tr key={i} >
    <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
    <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
    <td>{d.Address }</td> 
    <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.Department)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="submit" className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}  value="Delete"/></center></td>
 </tr>
}
```

PS:
the code itself is working so the console says nothing is wrong but i want it when i click it the table reloads

Comment: any useful output in the **developer** tools console or network tabs?

Comment: the code itself is working so it says nothing but i want it when i click it the table reloads

Comment: can you show your react component as well? not just the method, so we'll know how you handled the state.

Comment: @ickyrr the componentdidmount?

Comment: If the updated table data is in the response, you might want to use it to set your state. Your current code snippet doesn't look like it changes the jsonReturnedValue in any way. But ickyrr is right - if it's not a simple oversight then people are going to need to see more code to diagnose.

Comment: @speckledcarp what do you mean?

Comment: I tried to explain my meaning more fully in the answer below. But basically, I think you might have simply forgotten to update your table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Step 1 - You need to call index in your function`deleteEmployee(id,index)`
>
> Step 2 - Call Splice method after request end

```
  deleteEmployee(id, index) {
      jQuery.support.cors = true;
        fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
             method: 'GET'
      }).then(function(response) {
         // history.go(0);
          var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
          this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
      }).catch(function(err) {
        // Error :(
      });

   **this.state.jsonReturnedValue.splice(index, 1)**
///You can call as empty        
      this.setState({})

    }
```

EDIT/////

Also, the render shouldnt call as a function. You can use like that

```
     {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => <tr key={i} >
    <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
    <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
    <td>{d.Address }</td> 
    <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleOnclick.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID, d.Employee_Name, d.Address , d.Department)}   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="submit" className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}  value="Delete"/></center></td>
 </tr>)}
```

And then

```
onClick={this.deleteEmployee.(d.Employee_ID, i)}
```

you can call bind in constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
           example: ""
        }
        this.deleteEmployee = this.deleteEmployee.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: @Cracked - why do you say he shouldn't call the table row render as a function? That seems like perfectly reasonable modularization to me. It might be even better to make a separate component, but for one-off tables, that's probably fine.

Comment: @Cracked hey Its working thank you! :) sorry i dont have enough reputation to vote you up, you hepled a lot sir thank you

Comment: @speckledcarp - I wanted to ensure he understand. After he perceived to this event. Ofcourse best way is separated ones.

Comment: @Cracked im a girl tho hahaha , im just confuse sir i hope i can ask you if i use push for add and splice for delete.. what can i use for update?

Comment: Using Array.splice is a good solution to remove an item from an array. However, modifying the state directly is NOT! https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

It seems you are manually triggering a re-render by calling `setState({})`. Doesn't this erase all rows in the table?

Comment: @P.Macs hahaha, i couldnt guess :) I cant understand this time what do you mean

Comment: @Cracked sorry hahaha language barrier it's hard for me to explain in english.. im having problem on the update too should i use index too?

Comment: @speckledcarp Yes, you're right. But it works perfectly in this case. Also, ofcourse it doesnt erase :)

Comment: yeah i got it, No, you cant use splice function this time. Honestly, i dont know how to do :) I havent used before. But if i find a way, i write you

Comment: @Cracked I had a problem, i made a modal but the index cant be read :/ how can i pass the index to button to button?

Comment: @Cracked whats that?

Comment: @P.Macs send me a mail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing your list of employees in `this.state.jsonReturnedValue`. In your `deleteEmployee` function you make a copy of the array, but don't change any of the values. Presumably, you want to remove the row for the employee that was deleted before calling `this.setState` with the updated array.